# Étymologie de « ragoût »

Tags: étymologie, alimentation

Le [ragoût](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rago%C3%BBt) est un *plat de viande*. Il y a deux théories sur l'étymologie de ce nom. La première, qui est soutenue par le [Trésor de la Langue Française](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/ragout), le [Wiktionnaire anglais](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/rago%C3%BBt), la [Wikipédia anglaise](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ragout) et [celle Française](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rago%C3%BBt), affirme que ce nom dérive de l'ancien Français « ragoûter », de ra-/re-, goût, et le suffixe verbal -er, qui donc signifie « raviver le goût ». L'autre explication sur l'étymologie, soutenue seulement sur [ce site-ci](http://ilbazar.forumcommunity.net/?t=13132991) ([voici aussi un *screenshot*](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JKW89.png)), où on ne sait même pas écrire correctement « ragoût », l'écrivant avec un accent grave à la place d'un accent circonflexe, serait que ce nom dérive de « *rat au goût de boeuf* ». Comme lors de la guerre franco-prussienne, alors qu'on devait manger de la viande de rat et qu'on la cuisinait de manière à ce qu'elle ait le goût du bœuf, et ce « rat au goût », dit rapidement, se serait contracté en « ragoût ».

À ce point-ci il me semble assez évident que la deuxième étymologie ne tient pas la route. D'où vient-elle donc ? Comment est-elle née ? Y a-t-il d'autres sources fiables qui la soutiennent ?

Comment: Ce n'est pas une étymologie au sens propre, c'est l’accommodation d'un mot *ragoût*, aux vicissitudes des famines et privations organisées par les guerres de toutes sortes. Cet humour est la force de ceux qui n'ont plus rien, mais qui gardent leur humanité face à une réalité hostile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Un complément sur l'étymologie du *ragoût* comme tel. Au *TLFi* on dit que [ragoût](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/ragout) est attesté en 1623 pour l' « *assaisonnement, sauce excitant l'appétit* » et en 1665 pour « *mets, surtout plat de viande, préparé en sauce avec différentes épices* ». Il s'agit d'un déverbal de [*ragoûter*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/ragouter) (14<sup>e</sup> ; voir aussi au [*FEW/Wartburg*](https://apps.atilf.fr/lecteurFEW/index.php/page/lire/e/208444)), qui lui est construit sur [re-](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/re-), [a-](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/a-)(ad) et [*goût*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/gout) (13<sup>e</sup> pour *saveur*) et s'oppose à [*dégoûter*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/d%C3%A9gouter). On donne comme exemple d'attestation du ragoût (parfois anciennement *ragoust*) pour 1623 (l'espèce d'apéritif) et 1665 (le mets) respectivement :

> Il en pria un jour à souper des meilleurs drôles et qui avoient tout
>   dépensé le leur auprès des courtisanes ; il leur fit un festin
>   magnifique à six services : au premier étoient les entrées de table,
>   au second le gros du banquet, au troisième les [saupiquets](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/saupiquet) et les
>   **ragoûts**, au quatrième le dessert de fruits crus, au cinquième les
>   confitures et les dragées, mais pour le sixième il étoit merveilleux
>   et extraordinaire : il voulut faire lui-même le maître d’hôtel, et
>   apporta un grand bassin d’argent sur la table. L’on croyoit que ce fût
>   seulement pour laver les mains et qu’il alloit même faire donner les
>   cure-dents ; mais, le bassin étant sur la table, l’on vit qu’il y
>   avoit quantité de pièces d’or, desquelles il supplia la compagnie d’en
>   prendre chacun autant comme il voudroit.[...]
>
> [ [Charles Sorel](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Charles_Sorel) (1582/1602-1674) — [*La vraie histoire comique de Francion*](https://fr.wikisource.org/wiki/La_Vraie_Histoire_comique_de_Francion/Texte_entier) (autres éd. [1](https://books.google.com/books?id=NBFAAAAAcAAJ&printsec=frontcover&dq=Histoire.%20comique%20de%20Francion%20sorel&hl=fr&sa=X&ved=0CBMQ6AEwAGoVChMIuMnH2cT6xwIVklKSCh0jEQ4G#v=onepage&q=quastrieme&f=false) ;
>   [2](https://books.google.com/books?id=Eh46AAAAcAAJ&dq=Histoire.%20comique%20de%20Francion%20rago%C3%BBt&hl=fr&pg=PA503#v=onepage&q=rago%C3%BBts&f=false)) ]
>
> J'enrageais. Cependant on apporte un potage,
>  Un coq y paraissait
>   en pompeux équipage,
>  Qui, changeant sur ce plat et d'état et de
>   nom,
>  Par tous les conviés s'est appelé chapon.
>  Deux
>   assiettes suivaient, dont l'une était ornée
>  D'une langue en
>   **ragoût**, de persil couronnée ;
>  L'autre, d'un godiveau tout brûlé
>   par dehors,
>  Dont un beurre gluant inondait tous les bords.
>
> [ [Nicolas Boileau](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nicolas_Boileau) (1636-1711) — [*Les Satires*](https://fr.wikisource.org/wiki/Satire_III_%28Boileau%29) (autres éd.
>   [1](https://books.google.com/books?id=jrk5AAAAcAAJ&dq=Boileau%2C%20Satires&hl=fr&pg=PA17#v=onepage&q=ragout&f=false)) ]

La [*guerre franco-allemande*](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Guerre_franco-allemande_de_1870) à laquelle on réfère c'est 1870, comme on en traite [ailleurs](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/15993) dans le cadre d'une expression faisant référence au *rat* ; il y a évidemment homophonie entre *ra-* et *rat*, et des [jeux de mots](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jeu_de_mots) sont donc possibles. Mais le ragoût n'est pas une contraction, ni normalement un consommé, de rat, goûteux ou non.

Answer (score 3):

J'ai trouvé un commentaire [sur ce site](http://www.franceculture.fr/emission-on-ne-parle-pas-la-bouche-pleine-du-gout-et-du-ragout-2013-09-22) qui cite une revue du XIX siècle :

> En entendant le terme "Ragoût"( et ici la signification est symbolique -quoique...- ), je repense immanquablement à des articles que j'ai eu le plaisir de lire dans la revue "L' Illustration " de 1870-71 retraçant dans ses colonnes quasi au jour le jour le siège de Paris, décrivant les progressions des privations de la population, obligée pour se chauffer d'abattre les arbres, pour se nourrir d'éliminer progressivement toute trace de vie animale, depuis le Zoo jusqu'aux chevaux,chiens,chats et inventant des recettes et des intitulés à leurs menus afin de se permettre d'avaler sans trop de dégoût... Et c'est là que j'ai trouvé le terme de "Ragoût" qui désignait par euphémisme le dernier sursaut face à l'extrême indigence :
>   Le Rat au goût de Mouton .

Answer (score 0):

Le mot "ragù" existe en italien avec un sens presque identique du ragoût en français. Un "ragù" de bœuf n'est rien d'autre que la "sauce bolognèse". Je pense que l'origine du mot est bien plus ancienne que l'anecdote liée au siège prussien de Paris.